# How to stop Heroku from trying to install Husky

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, husky

I have a Node app (React) on Heroku and the deploy and build was previous working fine, I have now added Husky, Lint-staged, Craco and WDYR to a new branch which works locally.

Upon trying to deploy and build this branch on Heroku, I am finding that the build fails due to Heroku trying to install Husky despite me not asking it to and it being a development tool. It makes sense that Heroku cannot find Husky as it is a dev dependency.

From what I can see Heroku is running the `prepare` script from the client package.json, which it shouldn't be.

How can I stop Heroku from trying to install Husky?

Here are my package.json files (haven't included server package.json as I'm not sure it's relevant).

root

```
{
    "engines": {
        "node": "12.x"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "cd server && node server.js",
        "build": "cd client && npm run build",
        "install-server": "cd server && npm ci",
        "install-client": "cd client && npm ci",
        "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-server && npm run install-client && npm run build"
    }
}
```

client

```
{
    "name": "qupp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "App that allows users to create playlists using Spotify's API",
    "engines": {
        "node": "12.x"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build:css": "postcss src/App.scss -o src/index.css",
        "watch:css": "postcss src/App.scss -o src/index.css -w",
        "start_new": "PORT=3002 craco start",
        "start": "npm run watch:css & PORT=3002 craco start",
        "build": "npm run build:css && craco build",
        "test": "craco test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "prepare": "cd ../ && husky install ./client/.husky"
    },
    "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8082/",
    "author": "Daniel Blythe",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@craco/craco": "^6.3.0",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.17",
        "@types/materialize-css": "^1.0.6",
        "@types/node": "^12.7.1",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.1",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.5",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015-node6": "^0.4.0",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
        "firebase": "^8.2.4",
        "http2": "^3.3.7",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "morgan": "^1.9.1",
        "node-pre-gyp": "^0.11.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
        "postcss-cli": "^6.1.3",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
        "ramda": "^0.27.1",
        "re-base": "^4.0.0",
        "react": "^16.8.4",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
        "react-dropzone": "^10.0.0",
        "react-materialize": "^3.3.3",
        "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "react-spotify-player": "^1.0.4",
        "react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "source-map-support": "^0.5.9",
        "typescript": "^3.5.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/classnames": "^2.2.9",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.2",
        "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "^6.2.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
        "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.13.0",
        "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-no-autofix": "^1.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.1",
        "husky": "^7.0.2",
        "jest-dom": "^3.2.2",
        "lint-staged": "^11.1.2",
        "postcss": "^7.0.36",
        "postcss-cli": "^6.1.2",
        "prettier": "^2.3.2",
        "pretty-quick": "^3.1.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
        "react-testing-library": "^7.0.0",
        "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.14"
    },
    "jest": {
        "snapshotSerializers": [
            "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not ie <= 11",
        "not op_mini all"
    ]
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: This isn't an issue about Husky getting _installed_. Heroku _does_ install `devDependencies`, but then it strips them from the application after building. I believe Husky is getting installed just fine, but it isn't available when the `prepare` script runs. Exactly why this is running, I'm not sure. I don't do much Node.js. But it looks like it should run when you run `npm install`, which Heroku does.

Comment: Hi Chris, when you say 'should run' do you mean `prepare` should run when I run `npm install`? Isn't this wrong, I don't ask Heroku to run `prepare` and as `prepare` is a `git hook` it shouldn't get `run` at all on Heroku right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "`prepare` is a `git hook`", and again I'm not a Node.js dev so I'm likely missing something, but [it looks like the `prepare` script is designed to run automatically in a number of situations, including "on local `npm install` without any arguments"](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-scripts). I'm not sure what "local" means there, but Heroku runs `npm install` as part of its deploy process.

Comment: Ahh, this would certainly explain the failed build and come to think of it when I googled the `prepare` git hook, the actual git site mentioned `pre-commit` so I must be using `prepare` and just getting away it. Should I switch `prepare-commit` will I assume mean Heroku ignores it. Thanks Chris.

Comment: Come to think of it, this issue isn't to do with `pre-commit` it is indeed as Chris mentioned first, Husky isn't available when `prepare` is run and `prepare` is not a git hook, but is actually part of the `npm install` process (even though I'm using `npm ci`). I now need to look into a way of either making sure Husky is there when it's needed or a simpler fix of not using `prepare`; which wouldn't be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best solution:

run `npm ci --only=production --ignore-scripts`

https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/920

Following is from Heroku support ticket (I did not check this info):

> To cover the `--only=production` flag, you can set the environment
> variable `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true`
> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#only-installing-dependencies
>
> While it isn’t possible to add the `--ignore-scripts` flag to the
> install command directly, it can be set via npm config with npm config
> set ignore-scripts true and this will achieve the same thing during
> installation.
>
> The above command could be included using heroku-specific-build steps.
> e.g.;
>
> ```
> "scripts": {
>   "heroku-prebuild": "npm config set ignore-scripts true",
>   ...
> }
> ```

---

Alternative solution (but it has a drawback):

You can direct Heroku to only install dependencies by setting environment variables `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true` or `YARN_PRODUCTION=true`

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#only-installing-dependencies

This way you won't install devDependencies, assuming husky is in devDependencies (why would it not be?) meaning husky will never install.

The drawback is it won't install with any other devDependencies and i.e. I have there webpack which is required to run on build step. I don't want to move it from devDependencies to dependencies so I cant use this solution.